# Cannot Download Tectonic Sandbox

Tags: tectonic-coreos

I'm following instructions to installing the Tectonic Sandbox:
https://coreos.com/tectonic/docs/latest/tutorials/sandbox/install.html

It says to download the Tectonic Sandbox here:
https://coreos.com/tectonic/sandbox

But that link is broken.

Where can I download the Tectonic Sandbox?

Comment: Going by the domain name, it seems like the right people to ask would be the CoreOS people.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a frustration because most of the download links point to that link.

#### Download Link

https://coreos.com/tectonic/releases/

I posted an [issue](https://github.com/coreos/tectonic-forum/issues/299) on the tectonic forum to let them know!

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox has been lagging behind the regular Tectonic releases, and with the acquisition, we don't plan to update it further, which is why the download has been removed. All of the docs were supposed to have been removed, but clearly that is not the case ;)

If you want to check out the [old version](https://releases.tectonic.com/sandbox/tectonic-sandbox-1.7.5-tectonic.1.zip) (1.7.5) you can, but note that it doesn't reflect the latest Tectonic. If you'd like to check that out, I recommend [using AWS](https://coreos.com/tectonic/docs/latest/install/aws/aws-terraform.html) with 1.9.6, which was just released today.

You can also check out [Minishift](https://github.com/minishift/minishift), a local version of OpenShift. For more info on how Tectonic technology is being integrated, check out [this blog post](https://coreos.com/blog/coreos-tech-to-combine-with-red-hat-openshift).